# jquery setting cookie issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, cookies

I am setting a cookie on my page, using this plugin : https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

and out of my document ready function i added this :

```
 $.cookie('checkCook', '2')
```

after my document ready function i am doing some stuff and setting the cookie to null,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //setting the cokie

    if($.cookie('checkCook') == '2'){
        alert($.cookie('checkCook'));
         $.cookie('checkCook', null);
    }

})
```

But till i am getting the alert as '2', in every refresh of my browser. Anything wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are cleared by setting expiration time to past.

```
$.cookie('checkCook', null, {expires: new Date(1)})
```

Comment: That's not what the documentation says. `$.cookie('checkCook', null)` should suffice.

Comment: Yeah, seems that the latest plugin version puts expiration to past under to hood if you give literal null as value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have something set up like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //setting the cokie
    if($.cookie('checkCook') == '2'){
        alert($.cookie('checkCook'));
        $.cookie('checkCook', null);
    }
});
$.cookie('checkCook', '2');
```

What you are expecting is that your call to `$.cookie('checkCook', null);` will delete the cookie, but on every refresh of the page, the cookie is reset to '2' with your call to `$.cookie('checkCook', '2');`.

Since `$.cookie('checkCook', '2');` is outside of your doc.ready function, it gets called as soon as the browser hits it (remember, the page is loaded top down), and the doc.ready block is delayed until the dom is loaded.  This means that the `$.cookie('checkCook', '2');` code is executed **before** the doc.ready block.  That's why you are always getting the alert that states the value is '2'. The cookie is getting **set** on every page refresh, and before your `alert` is called.

What you could do is wrap the cookie setting code in a function and call that from doc.ready. This will delay the setting of the cookie until **after** the alert code is executed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //setting the cokie
    if($.cookie('checkCook') == '2'){
        alert($.cookie('checkCook'));
        $.cookie('checkCook', null);
    }

    setCookie();
});

function setCookie()
{
    $.cookie('checkCook', '2');
}
```